# Limit number of partitions for spark.read pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

After I read xml files using spark:

```
df = spark.read\
        .format("xml")\
        .options(**options)\
        .load("s3a://.../.../")
```

I checked the number of partitions with `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`, and got 20081.

How do I limit the number of partitions at the start so I don't have to do a `coalesce()` later? The issue with having so many partitions is due to each partition creates one file during `df.write`, and 20081 new very small files in s3 each time this process runs is very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting Dataframe of `spark.read` will always match the number of partitions with the number of files because each file will be read by a dedicated task.

If you need to run this process more often I would rather have those original 20000 files consumed  and copied *once* into lesser files using `coalesce` or `repartition`. Then, all subsequent reads of those files will result in a Dataframe with lesser partitions.

Answer (score 1):

The number of partitions is calculated by [DataSourceScanExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/DataSourceScanExec.scala) via a bit complex formula. However to simplify it, try to increase this value `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`, it is `134217728` (128 MB) by default. Try to make it larger and you will see the difference.

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes', '1073741824') # 1 GB
```